# How to use appium inspector to find the xpath of android app elements on on a real device

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, webdriver, appium

I am new to appium. I am using appium with selenium Webdriver(using JAVA) on Mavericks. I have done the setup for appium. I downloaded a sample testcase for android calculator app. I started the appium server from terminal and I was able to run the testcase successfully. Now I want to test my android application. How to find the xpath of the elements using inspector. Provide any support links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please accept the answer by SthQA, since it seems relevant to the question mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 3):

The easier answer would be to use the Appium GUI. You can open your server from terminal or from GUI but I would suggest the GUI since stuff are easier that way.

If you happen to open a server from terminal then you have to tick the "use remote server" and enter the server address. After doing so click the magnifier(Inspector button) and you can look at each items xpath/id/classname etc

Since this is not a hard issue as I understand I suggest you take a look at it from the [appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.1/?ruby#appium-gui)- Note that the documentation shows images of w8 version as osx but it is the same idea.

If you have a specific question regarding the process be open to ask.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to record the login functionality using inspector. After entering email, password-I tried clicking Signin Button. I am getting error in the app as(No Network available). Network issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess your email password is regarding the app you are trying to test on since appium has nothing regarding what you just stated. To be frank I have not encountered a 'no network available' issue. You may ask in another question regarding that.

Comment: I want to know if I missed any settings. When I start appium server, this is how it looks.(http://www.dropmocks.com/mG0eV1). And My General settings is (http://www.dropmocks.com/mGzrFT).

Comment: What i am trying to understand is if you can inspect your app or not? If you have problems opening the inspect use the prelaunch option and give the necessary values in the android icon (App-path is generally the only thing mandatory if you have a connected device)

Comment: Sorry. I didnt mention the prblm clearly. Following is my scnenario. Click email ID and enter email. Click Password field and enter password. Click SigninButton. So, I opened Inspector and Clicked Record button. I entered email and password. When I click sigin button(during recording process), alert is shown in the emulator as **No Network Available**. This alert we will get in the app when we try to access the app without Wifi. So, it seems like i am trying to access the app in offine. How to overcome this?

Comment: I can't acquaint you with emulator knowledge. for that you will have to ask somebody else. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

the best two UI inspector are from Appium and from Android studio:

path to Android Studio:

> .../AndroidSDK/tools/uiautomatorviewer;

or Appium in GUI.

But for me Android is much better, and You can choose from devices if You have multiple.